# ResourcePatternUtils.getResourcePatternResolver(resourceLoader) get two resource

Tags: java, spring

I don't know what the difference is between these two paths, why I'm getting two almost identical paths. It works fine when I use it in IntelliJ IDEA.

Resource----------------->: jar:file:/Users/wanggang/Documents/jar中转站/cmcc-cloud-devops-1.0.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/cmcc/cloud/devops/facade/HuaWeiApi.class
Resource----------------->: jar:file:/Users/wanggang/Documents/jar中转站/cmcc-cloud-devops-1.0.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes/com/cmcc/cloud/devops/facade/HuaWeiApi.class

```
@Component
public class RpcPostProcessor implements ResourceLoaderAware,BeanFactoryPostProcessor  {
    private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;
    @Override
    public void setResourceLoader(ResourceLoader resourceLoader) {
        this.resourceLoader = resourceLoader;
    }

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        try {
            //获取指定目录下的class文件
            org.springframework.core.io.Resource[] resources = ResourcePatternUtils.getResourcePatternResolver(resourceLoader)
                    .getResources("classpath*:/**/facade/**/*.class");
            //根据resources创建数据读取工厂
            MetadataReaderFactory metaReader = new CachingMetadataReaderFactory(resourceLoader);
            for (org.springframework.core.io.Resource resource : resources) {
                //获取元数据
                MetadataReader metadataReader = metaReader.getMetadataReader(resource);
                //判断是否存在HttpExchange注解(是否为http interface的接口调用)
                if (metadataReader.getAnnotationMetadata().hasAnnotation(HttpExchange.class.getName())) {
                    //构建一个web客户端
                    WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder().build();
                    //根据web客户端去构建服http服务的代理工厂
                    HttpServiceProxyFactory factory = HttpServiceProxyFactory.builder(WebClientAdapter.forClient(webClient)).build();
                    //利用类的全限定名通过Class.forName获取class对象并利用http服务的代理工厂创建出代理对象
                    Object client = factory.createClient(Class.forName(metadataReader.getClassMetadata().getClassName()));
                    //将创建出来的代理对象放到io容器当中
                    String className = metadataReader.getClassMetadata().getClassName();
                    beanFactory.registerSingleton(className, client);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new EventException(ES_RPC_000);
        }
    }
}
```

but in Mac OS or linux is not working